# Solving a low rank symmetric system

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, approximation

I'm working on a problem where I need to solve a large set of systems of equations, where each has a structure that looks like:

$\left( M^\top_{n\times p}\Sigma_{p\times p} M_{p\times n} + \Lambda_{n\times n}\right)  x_{n\times 1} = b_{n\times 1}$,

where

- Here $p \sim 30$ and $n \sim O(1e5)$
- $\Sigma$ is a positive definite symmetric $p\times p$ matrix
- $\Lambda$ is a positive definite diagonal $n\times n$ matrix
- $M$ is a general $p\times n$ matrix.

Could anyone point me to techniques / algorithms for fast solutions of this problem. I'm open to non-iterative ( eg Cholesky type decompositions of the LHS matrix ), iterative and even approximate techniques.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look for Sherman, Morrison and Woodbury. This one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity (in generalization of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)
$$ 
\left(A+UCV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}.
$$

Comment: I'm currently using this approach .. but I'm still spending a lot of time in the multiplication of A\inv, U and V with the central block. I would prefer an algorithm that directly solves the system without inverting and with much better complexity.